# Get selected text separated by lines

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I am trying to get the selected text separated by lines to make a VSCODE Extension.

```
    const document = editor.document;
    const selection = editor.selection;
    const position = editor.selection.end;
    const word = document.getText(selection);
```

I didnt find the command to separate the selection in array for example.

Someone has the solution and the link of the API, for document constructor ?

I tried a .split("/n") without result too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to identify the newline. In Unix and Windows systems there are two types of characters that can cause newlines.

- `CR` or `\r` - Carriage Return (Windows)
- `LF` or `\n` - Line Feed (Unix)

So in you system you should split the selected string by both chracters.

```js
const splittedStringArray = selectedText.split(/\r?\n/);
```

Comment: I am at Windows, so that was the problem, thanks for the explanation.